# Are subhead, lead and nutshell paragraph considered text types or display types?

Tags: typography

to contextualize my post:

> Text Type is type that is designed to be read in large quantities at
> small sizes.…For example, the bulk of the text in any newspaper,
> magazine, or book is Text Type.…
> It's also called Body Type or Body Copy.…Display type,
>
> on the other hand, is type that 14 point or larger, and it's typically used…
> in small quantities for emphasis and effect.…

Since subhead, lead and nutshell paragraph are placed between the head of the article -display type- and the content of the article -text types- I m wondering at which category they typically belong. I know the factual answer could be something like -it depends of the length of your section. That said I assume their is some general practice about that part of articles, and it would be cool to have some general guidance about this point.

here two illustrations:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, can you please explain your issue better? Can you add a sketch what you mean with "subhead" etc.? Which software do you use for creating documents? Please be more specific ...

Comment: @Kurt thanks for your answer, okay I have modified my post, hope I have made it more specific and limpid